# Get text from pdf file in Java without using any library other than default Java APIs

Tags: java, pdf

I know that getting text from a pdf file is relatively easy when we use some libraries eg. pdfbox. Nevertheless, is there any guide about doing this task with only default Java APIs? Something similar to the DOM API when we parse xml file but for pdf file.

Comment: Why? You will only end up reimplementing PDFBox. This is a non-trivial task. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @user207421 Generally using third party libraries is convenient. However in some circumstances, for instance I only need to obtain text from pdf file, I don't need other APIs of PDFBox. Why do I have to import the whole PDFBox library ?

Comment: So as not to have to rewrite any of it. This is a cost, and PDFBox is free. And I am telling you it will be a major cost, in both money and time. It isn't your job to waste either.

Comment: Totally agree with @user207421. While I am fully supporting approach to do not add in the project unnecessary libs ( specifically, I hate when something like apache-commons-* is added just to save one line of code in one place), parsing PDF is a pretty complex operation, which is much better to delegate to the well-known library

Comment: @OleksandrBereziuk Maybe I will do it by myseft, and post it as an answer. Hopefully it will be useful for someone who is looking for a guidance, like me at the moment.

Comment: Good luck with that, PDFBox was done in 46 person-years according to Openhub. You could of course take PDFBox and remove rendering and utilities, but you'd have to repeat this for every new version.